# Can the Dispatch Queue in iOS be persisted to disk so it can be resumed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is the Dispatch Queue reliable? If I use it for sending outgoing web service messages and the server is offline, so they queue up, can I persist the Dispatch Queue to disk when the application is closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dispatch queues are not serializable; neither are blocks.